# Pointer has address before if/else statement but changes to 0x0 right away

Tags: c, pointers, tree

So this code searches for one of the strings in a tree (input by array of strings). The search doesn't work properly because the printf("%p", treePtr) shows that treePtr has an address but changes to 0x0 immediately for some reason, thus returning null.

```
Output: 

0x7f9c50c02680

0x0
```

I've tried different combinations such as: &treePtr and *treePtr, but they don't work.

```
    /*
(Binary Tree Search)
 Write function binaryTreeSearch that attempts to locate a specified
value in a binary search tree. The function should take as arguments a pointer to the root node of
the binary tree and a search key to be located. If the node containing the search key is found, the
function should return a pointer to that node; otherwise, the function should return a NULL pointer.
*/
//ANS:


/* Exercise Solution */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
 /* TreeNode structure definition */
struct TreeNode
{
  struct TreeNode *leftPtr; /* pointer to left subtree */
  char data[9];         /* node data */
  struct TreeNode *rightPtr;    /* pointer to right subtree */
};              /* end struct TreeNode */

typedef struct TreeNode TreeNode;
typedef TreeNode *TreeNodePtr;

 /* function prototypes */
void insertNode (TreeNodePtr * treePtr, char value[]);
TreeNodePtr binaryTreeSearch (TreeNodePtr treePtr, char key[]);

int main (void)
{
  int i;
  const char * item[] = {"cea", "riz", "mac", "roz", "bee", "lea", "tee", "pee", "see"};            /* loop counter */
  char searchKey[3];        /* value to search for */
  TreeNodePtr rootPtr = NULL;   /* points to the tree root */
  TreeNodePtr searchResultPtr;  /* pointer to search result */

  printf ("The strings being placed in the tree are:\n");

  for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
      printf ("%s\t", item[i]);
      insertNode (&rootPtr, item[i]);
    }       /* end for */

  /* prompt user and read integer search key */
  printf ("\n\nEnter a string to search for: ");
  scanf ("%s", searchKey);
  printf ("%s", searchKey );
  searchResultPtr = binaryTreeSearch (rootPtr, searchKey);

  /* if searchKey not found */
  if (searchResultPtr == NULL)
    {
      printf ("\n%s was not found in the tree.\n\n", searchKey);
    }               /* end if */
  else
    {               /* if key found */
      printf ("\n%s was found in the tree.\n\n", searchResultPtr->data);
    }               /* end else */

  getchar();
  getchar();
  return 0;         /* indicate successful termination */
}               /* end main */

 /* insert a node into the tree */
void insertNode (TreeNodePtr * treePtr, char value[])
{
  /* if treePtr is NULL */
  if (*treePtr == NULL)
    {
      /* dynamically allocate memory */
      *treePtr = malloc (sizeof (TreeNode));

      /* if memory was allocated, insert node */
      if (*treePtr != NULL)
    {
      strcpy((*treePtr)->data,  value);
      (*treePtr)->leftPtr = NULL;
      (*treePtr)->rightPtr = NULL;
    }           /* end if */
      else
    {
      printf ("%s not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
    }           /* end else */
    }               /* end if */
  else
    {               /* recursively call insertNode */
      /* insert node in left subtree */
      if (value < (*treePtr)->data)
    {
      insertNode (&((*treePtr)->leftPtr), value);
    }           /* end if */
      else
    {
      /* insert node in right subtree */
      if (value > (*treePtr)->data)
        {
          insertNode (&((*treePtr)->rightPtr), value);
        }           /* end if */
      else
        {           /* duplicate value */
          printf ("dup");
        }           /* end else */
    }           /* end else */
    }               /* end else */
}               /* end function insertNode */

 /* search for key in tree */
TreeNodePtr binaryTreeSearch (TreeNodePtr treePtr, char key[])
{
  /* traverse the tree inOrder */
  if (treePtr == NULL)
    {
      printf("%p\n", treePtr);

      return NULL;      /* key not found */
    }               /* end if */
  else if (treePtr->data == key)
    {
      return treePtr;       /* key found */
    }               /* end else if */
  else if (key < treePtr->data)
    {
      return binaryTreeSearch (treePtr->leftPtr, key);  /* search left */
    }               /* end else if */
  else // (key > treePtr->data)
    {
      return binaryTreeSearch (treePtr->rightPtr, key); /*search right */
    }               /* end else if */
}               /* end function binaryTreeSearch */
```

Comment: Your code seems to have lost some line breaks. Please put them back for the question. =)

Comment: The code is not a MCVE. The only printf that could possibly print a pointer value is guarded by `treePtr == NULL` so it could only print the NULL pointer, not 0x7f9c50c02680. Now what is the *actual* code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (value > (*treePtr)->data)
```

This is not the way to compare strings in C. This code will compare the address of the strings, not the actual value of them. To compare strings, you must use the [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function. For example, to test if a string is greater (lexicographical-wise) than another, use `strcmp` like so:

```
if (strcmp(string1, string2) > 0)
```

This means that `string1`, is greater than `string2` lexicographical-wise. Go through your code and update the comparisons to use `strcmp`.

The line

```
char searchKey[3];
```

can cause bugs. `searchKey` does not have enough room for the null terminator at the end. Make sure you change the 3 to a 4.

Last but not least, `scanf` is not a safe way to get user input. It can lead to buffer overflows. I suggest using [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). That way, you can specify how much input you desire.

```
fgets(searchKey, sizeof(searchKey), stdin);
```

Comment: According to the C11 specification: *"The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2."* Which is to say that expecting `strcmp` to return `1` is not wise. Although some conforming implementations work that way, many do not.

Comment: I've changed it to > or < 0.it works better but now, but still wont search for the node